# Image button not visible inside a table cell

Tags: html, css

**My html code is**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="image" style="height:25px; width:25px;" src="plus.png"></td>
</tr>
```

The cell is being created but image is not showing. However, if I use `img` tag, it is showing, so no problem with image's src.

EDIT: The CSS linked maybe the problem, but cannot figure out what:-

```
    *{
        font-family: Arial, sans;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 1em 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
    }

    #container input {
        height: 2.5em;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #container label {
        background: #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
        color: #888;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-size: 1em;
        height: 2.5em;
        line-height: 2.5em;
        margin-right: .25em;
        padding: 0 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #container input:hover + label {
        background: #ddd;
        color: #666;
    }

    #container input:checked + label {
        background: #DBF3FD;
        color: #444;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 6;
        /*
        -webkit-transition: .1s;
        -moz-transition: .1s;
        -o-transition: .1s;
        -ms-transition: .1s;
        */
    }

    #content {
        background: #DBF3FD;
        border-radius: 0 .25em .25em .25em;
        min-height: 18em;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    #content div {
        opacity: 0;
        padding: 1.5em;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -100;
    }

    #content-1 p {
        clear: both;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    #content-1 p.last {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #content-2 p {
        float: left;
        width: 48.5%;
    }
    #content-2 p.column-right {
        margin-left: 3%;
    }

    #content-3 p {
        float: left;
        width: 48.5%;
    }
    #content-3 p.column-right {
        margin-left: 3%;
    }

    #container input#tab-1:checked ~ #content #content-1,
    #container input#tab-2:checked ~ #content #content-2,
    #container input#tab-3:checked ~ #content #content-3 
    {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    input.visible {
      visibility: visible !important;
    }
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    tr:hover{background-color:#96DCF7}
```

Comment: try including the folder the img file is located within, e.g. `src="images/plus.png"`

Comment: What is this `type="image"` ?>

Comment: Please go through https://www.w3schools.com there u can see lot of examples and the way to create

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you write that input:

```
input.visible {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

But you also have:

```
input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

You never refer to the .visible class on the code you show us, so it stays hidden. Maybe this is the problem. Try adding `class="visible"` to the input.

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <input class="visible" type="image" style="height:25px; width:25px;" src="plus.png">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with css. Add `style=" background-image: url("plus.png");"` to input tag. `input type="image"` is not valid property of type attribute.

Comment: Yes. It is a valid type. Directly from w3schools:
<input type="image" src="img_submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48">

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the other code interacting with your html. The following code works for me:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="image" src="Image.png"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe you should start here and then add your styles back little by little until you find whatever caused the problem.

EDIT: I copied all the code you have put here and assumed that you had a div with an id of container and another div with an id of content and that your table lived in there. Following @Benjamin Naesen's advice I set the visibility to visible and the picture appeared.

```
input.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Did this work for you?